# SQL Select records within a value range in a given period of time

Tags: mysql, sql, database, view

I have an Sql table HC_RSPI and i want to select and present records
only if a value of a field is within a range in a period of time let's say
5 or 7 days in a row from multiple records.

```
| RADIO_TYPE |   HOP |         TOWARDS | RSPI |       TP_NAME |          DATE_TIME_END | TIME_LENGTH | RLTM_min | RLTM_max |
|------------|-------|-----------------|------|---------------|------------------------|-------------|----------|----------|
| FlexiMetro | H3376 |         RAPSANI | RSPI | ODU 1 Radio 1 | June, 10 2015 00:00:00 |       86400 |       65 |       37 |
| FlexiMetro | H3376 |         RAPSANI | RSPI | ODU 2 Radio 2 | June, 10 2015 00:00:00 |       86400 |       74 |       47 |
| FlexiMetro | H3178 | NEAPOLI_LARISSA | RSPI | ODU 1 Radio 1 | June, 10 2015 00:00:00 |       86406 |       37 |       32 |
| FlexiMetro | H3178 | NEAPOLI_LARISSA | RSPI | ODU 2 Radio 2 | June, 10 2015 00:00:00 |       86406 |       48 |       43 |
| FlexiMetro | H3376 |      TYRNAVOS_2 | RSPI | ODU 1 Radio 1 | June, 10 2015 00:00:00 |       86396 |       42 |       36 |
| FlexiMetro | H3376 |      TYRNAVOS_2 | RSPI | ODU 2 Radio 2 | June, 10 2015 00:00:00 |       86396 |       52 |       46 |
| FlexiMetro | H3301 |         LICHADA | RSPI | ODU 1 Radio 1 | June, 10 2015 00:00:00 |       86399 |       58 |       47 |
| FlexiMetro | H3301 |         LICHADA | RSPI | ODU 2 Radio 2 | June, 10 2015 00:00:00 |       86399 |       67 |       56 |
| FlexiMetro | H3390 |        SKIATHOS | RSPI | ODU 1 Radio 1 | June, 10 2015 00:00:00 |       86397 |       63 |       48 |
| FlexiMetro | H3390 |        SKIATHOS | RSPI | ODU 2 Radio 2 | June, 10 2015 00:00:00 |       86397 |       70 |       56 |
| FlexiMetro | H3178 |     LARISSA_MTX | RSPI | ODU 1 Radio 1 | June, 10 2015 00:00:00 |       86400 |       38 |       33 |
| FlexiMetro | H3178 |     LARISSA_MTX | RSPI | ODU 2 Radio 2 | June, 10 2015 00:00:00 |       86400 |       48 |       44 |
| FlexiMetro | H3442 |       ANCHIALOS | RSPI | ODU 1 Radio 1 | June, 10 2015 00:00:00 |       86400 |       53 |       47 |
| FlexiMetro | H3376 |         RAPSANI | RSPI | ODU 1 Radio 1 | June, 09 2015 00:00:00 |       86400 |       70 |       37 |
| FlexiMetro | H3376 |         RAPSANI | RSPI | ODU 2 Radio 2 | June, 09 2015 00:00:00 |       86400 |       74 |       47 |
| FlexiMetro | H3376 |         RAPSANI | RSPI | ODU 1 Radio 1 | June, 08 2015 00:00:00 |       86400 |       65 |       37 |
| FlexiMetro | H3376 |         RAPSANI | RSPI | ODU 2 Radio 2 | June, 08 2015 00:00:00 |       86400 |       74 |       47 |
| FlexiMetro | H3376 |         RAPSANI | RSPI | ODU 1 Radio 1 | June, 07 2015 00:00:00 |       86400 |       65 |       37 |
| FlexiMetro | H3376 |         RAPSANI | RSPI | ODU 2 Radio 2 | June, 07 2015 00:00:00 |       86400 |       74 |       47 |
| FlexiMetro | H3376 |         RAPSANI | RSPI | ODU 1 Radio 1 | June, 06 2015 00:00:00 |       86400 |       65 |       37 |
| FlexiMetro | H3376 |         RAPSANI | RSPI | ODU 2 Radio 2 | June, 06 2015 00:00:00 |       86400 |       74 |       47 |
```

I want to know if for example RLTM_min is within a value range let's say 65 - 85 within a period of time let's say 4 or 5 days in row which means i have a problem.
In our example H3376 RAPSANI ODU 1 Radio 1 and ODU Radio 2 are within that range(65 - 85) for 4 days in a row i want only these records.

The output could be.

```
| RADIO_TYPE |   HOP | TOWARDS | RSPI |       TP_NAME |          DATE_TIME_END | TIME_LENGTH | RLTM_min | RLTM_max |
|------------|-------|---------|------|---------------|------------------------|-------------|----------|----------|
| FlexiMetro | H3376 | RAPSANI | RSPI | ODU 1 Radio 1 | June, 10 2015 00:00:00 |       86400 |       65 |       37 |
| FlexiMetro | H3376 | RAPSANI | RSPI | ODU 2 Radio 2 | June, 10 2015 00:00:00 |       86400 |       74 |       47 |
| FlexiMetro | H3376 | RAPSANI | RSPI | ODU 1 Radio 1 | June, 09 2015 00:00:00 |       86400 |       70 |       37 |
| FlexiMetro | H3376 | RAPSANI | RSPI | ODU 2 Radio 2 | June, 09 2015 00:00:00 |       86400 |       74 |       47 |
| FlexiMetro | H3376 | RAPSANI | RSPI | ODU 1 Radio 1 | June, 08 2015 00:00:00 |       86400 |       65 |       37 |
| FlexiMetro | H3376 | RAPSANI | RSPI | ODU 2 Radio 2 | June, 08 2015 00:00:00 |       86400 |       74 |       47 |
| FlexiMetro | H3376 | RAPSANI | RSPI | ODU 1 Radio 1 | June, 07 2015 00:00:00 |       86400 |       65 |       37 |
| FlexiMetro | H3376 | RAPSANI | RSPI | ODU 2 Radio 2 | June, 07 2015 00:00:00 |       86400 |       74 |       47 |
| FlexiMetro | H3376 | RAPSANI | RSPI | ODU 1 Radio 1 | June, 06 2015 00:00:00 |       86400 |       65 |       37 |
| FlexiMetro | H3376 | RAPSANI | RSPI | ODU 2 Radio 2 | June, 06 2015 00:00:00 |       86400 |       74 |       47 |
```

Or only the HOP with TOWARDS and TP_NAME to state which of them have a problem.

Is there a way to implement this in a sql query?
How do i implement this ? create another table ,do a join?Create a view ?

Thank you

[SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ad722/4)

Answer (score 0):

```
select  distinct HC_RSPI_data.*
from    (
        select
            firstDay.RADIO_TYPE
        ,   firstDay.HOP       
        ,   firstDay.TOWARDS   
        ,   firstDay.RSPI      
        ,   firstDay.TP_NAME   
        ,   firstDay.DATE_TIME_END                    as  periodBegins
        ,   (firstDay.DATE_TIME_END + INTERVAL 6 DAY) as  periodEnds
        from    HC_RSPI_data            as  firstDay
            inner join  HC_RSPI_data    as  followingDay
                on  followingDay.RADIO_TYPE     =   firstDay.RADIO_TYPE
                and followingDay.HOP            =   firstDay.HOP            
                and followingDay.TOWARDS        =   firstDay.TOWARDS        
                and followingDay.RSPI           =   firstDay.RSPI           
                and followingDay.TP_NAME        =   firstDay.TP_NAME        
                and followingDay.DATE_TIME_END  between firstDay.DATE_TIME_END and (firstDay.DATE_TIME_END + INTERVAL 6 DAY)
                and (   -- Days when RLTM_min or RLTM_max is between 65-85
                        followingDay.RLTM_min between 65 and 85 
                    or  followingDay.RLTM_max between 65 and 85 
                )
        where   (       -- Days when RLTM_min or RLTM_max is between 65-85
                        firstDay.RLTM_min between 65 and 85 
                    or  firstDay.RLTM_max between 65 and 85 
                )
        group by 
            firstDay.RADIO_TYPE
        ,   firstDay.HOP       
        ,   firstDay.TOWARDS   
        ,   firstDay.RSPI      
        ,   firstDay.TP_NAME   
        ,   firstDay.DATE_TIME_END
        having  sum(1) = 7  -- a period of 7 days with matching values
    )   as  period
    inner join HC_RSPI_data
        on  HC_RSPI_data.RADIO_TYPE      =   period.RADIO_TYPE     
        and HC_RSPI_data.HOP             =   period.HOP            
        and HC_RSPI_data.TOWARDS         =   period.TOWARDS        
        and HC_RSPI_data.RSPI            =   period.RSPI           
        and HC_RSPI_data.TP_NAME         =   period.TP_NAME        
        and HC_RSPI_data.DATE_TIME_END    between period.periodBegins and period.periodEnds
;
```

Comment: Have you tried It to sql fiddle because it throws an error FUNCTION db_9_ad722.dateadd does not exist what could be wrong i tried with date_add also. And if i want to check for RTLM_max too i just add or  and followingDay.RLTM_min       between 65 and 85 
        where   firstDay.RLTM_min between 65 and 85  or followingDay.RLTM_max       between 65 and 85 
        where   firstDay.RLTM_max between 65 and 85 Correct?

Comment: Oh right! I used your SQL Fiddle link and fixed the bugs. Thanks for the tip. It also now picks days when min or max is between 65-85.

Comment: I corrected it my self yesterday  like you have but something is wrong even if it works at SQLfiddle it's giving me an error in phpmyadmin. #1064 - You have an error in you SQL syntax;
check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'AS' at line 4

Comment: Are you sure you are running MySQL v5.6 as the Fiddle is set to? Try to remove "as" keywords.